# Trigger is running even if I create a new lead

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code, apex

As per the below code, this meant to update the first and last name only if I update a new lead but it is updating the first and last name of new lead as well 
Can someone please suggest. Thank you!

```
  trigger HelloWorld on Lead (before update) {
    for(Lead l : Trigger.new){
    l.FirstName = 'Hello';
    l.LastName = 'World';
    }
    }
```

Comment: Really goog question. It seems that the Lead object is a bit speciall. I have checked the logs and whenever a normal lead is created the insert as well the update trigger are called.

Comment: it only happens in salesforce lightening in classic it works good, I don't know the reason behind the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a workflow or process builder field update action on the lead object?  If so it would trigger an update on the record that was newly inserted thus would fire the trigger.

So in lightning there is s default Lead assignment rule that is active, if you disable it, the update doesn't happen.  But it is weird  that the rule causes an update in Lightning but not in classic, so that might still be a bug that should be reported to Salesforce.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, I have created a new org and after that, the first thing I did was created this trigger so there are no workflows and nothing from process builder or visual workflow and moreover this works fine in salesforce classic but in lightening it changes the name even for the new record

Comment: I think I'll check this out myself when I have some time

Comment: Thank you, Gareth!

Comment: You are absolutely correct this is happening, seems to me that there might be a bug with lightning